# Powershell import-csv splitting and matching cell contents

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV with 3 columns and multiple rows. Each of the 3 x neighboring cells (per row) has multiple lines of data in the cell, always with the same number of lines per neighboring cell.

[image]

Raw CSV data:

```
NodeName,NodeAddress,NodeAdressDR
"1.com
2.com
3.com
4.com","10.173.5.210
10.173.5.212
10.173.5.214
10.173.5.216","10.49.245.210
10.49.245.212
10.49.245.214
10.49.245.216"
"5.com
6.com
7.com
8.com","10.173.5.203
10.173.5.205
10.173.5.207","10.49.245.203
10.49.245.205
10.49.245.207"
,,
```

This is working with the following but is there an easier way to cater for indeterminate number of hostnames/IPs per cell without having to create the individual variables i.e one per line?

```
$csvImportFull = Import-CSV .\CSVFile.csv
foreach ($headingFull in $csvImportFull)

{
$nodeName = $headingFull.("NodeName")
$nodeAddress =$headingFull.("NodeAddress")
$nodeAddressDR = $headingFull.("NodeAddressDR")

$NodeName1 = ($nodeName -split "\n")[0]
$NodeName2 = ($nodeName-split "\n")[1]
$NodeName3 = ($nodeName-split "\n")[2]
$NodeName4 = ($nodeName -split "\n")[3]

$NodeAddress1 = ($nodeAddress -split "\n")[0]
$NodeAddress2 = ($nodeAddress -split "\n")[1]
$NodeAddress3 = ($nodeAddress -split "\n")[2]
$NodeAddress4 = ($nodeAddress -split "\n")[3]

$NodeAddressDR1 = ($nodeAddressDR -split "\n")[0]
$NodeAddressDR2 = ($nodeAddressDR -split "\n")[1]
$NodeAddressDR3 = ($nodeAddressDR -split "\n")[2]
$NodeAddressDR4 = ($nodeAddressDR -split "\n")[3]

write-host $NodeName1 NodeAddress1
write-host $NodeName1 NodeAddressDR1
write-host $NodeName2 NodeAddress2
write-host $NodeName1 NodeAddressDR2
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample csv with at least 2 records?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to file sharing facilities from work but I've added an image.

Comment: What is the delimiter? Is it tab? Also what is your goal? You probably want an object containing a list of (4) nodenames, a list of (4) address and same for addressDR for each record? Right?

Comment: I'm trying to match the lines in the rows because the spreadsheet has multiple lines per cell which makes it difficult to process because there is effectively one hostname "NodeName" that can have two IP addresses "NodeAddress" & "NodeAddressDR" so I have to use the newline as a separator.

Comment: ah, got it. I need an example csv to help you further.

Comment: Okay I have added the file.

Comment: I've re-arranged and edited your question to include the sample CSV data. So you know for next time, simple text based data be placed between `<pre> </pre>` tags within your question, this is easier to see than using a google drive link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of hard writing the variables you could iterate over the split and greate a new list of objects:

```
$objects = @()

Import-CSV .\CSVFile.csv| ForEach-Object {
    $names = $_.NodeName -split '\r\n'
    $address = $_.NodeAddress -split '\r\n'
    $addressDr = $_.NodeAdressDR -split '\r\n'

    for($i = 0; $i -le 4; $i++)
    {
        $objects += [PsCustomObject]@{                
        NodeName = $names[$i]
            NodeAddress = $address[$i]
            NodeAddressDr = $addressDr[$i]
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a list of objects where each object has a `NodeName`, `NodeAddress` and `NodeAddressDR`

So you can do something like this:

```
$objects | where NodeName -eq '1.com'
```

Output:

```
NodeName NodeAddress  NodeAddressDr
-------- -----------  -------------
1.com    10.173.5.210 10.49.245.210
```